# Post Request using python

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post, python-requests-html

I was trying to make a script in Python for the automatic filling of a webpage, obviously giving the ight inputs and then getting the output generated by the webpage, but I'm new with Python so I'm a little lost.
The webpage I'm trying to work with is this one:
https://t-ict4d.ictp.it/nequick2/nequick-2-web-model

I already saw the page source code and opened the "nequick.js"

There I found the datastring needed and already made it on python, giving all variables values previously on the code:
`datastring = { "lat1":"lat1", "lon1":"lon1", "h1":"h1", "lat2":"lat2", "lon2":"lon2", "h2":"h2", "year":"year", "month":"month", "day":"day", "hour":"hour", "localtime":"localtime", "user":"user", "r12_f":"r12_f", "sol_val":"sol_val", "itu":"itu" }`

but then when I do `requests.post(url,data=datastring)`, the output is not the output that I want from that webpage.

Does anyone know what's missing for me to get the output like when the webpage is filled directly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The way you're creating your dictionary is wrong, should be:

```
"lat1":lat1,"lon1":lon1,"h1":h1,...
```

Have a look here if you're having some trouble: [Python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Okey, thank you!
That was one mistake, but the output is still not correct

Answer (score 0):

You will try this way

```
r = request.post(url,data=datastring)
print(r.json()) or print(r.text)
```